# heroku assets:precompile error for foundation sites $color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, zurb-foundation, bower

I have an "angular of rails" app using foundation-sites which I'm installing with bower.

Whenever I try to push to heroku, it breaks on running `rake assets:precompile` with the following error:

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: $color: "foreground(#09798e)" is not a color for `red'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/_color.scss:19:in `foundation-badge'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:21
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/app/assets/stylesheets/cguides.scss:1
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:310:in `reformat_argument_error'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:149:in `rescue in _perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:123:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `block in _perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:471:in `visit_variable'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_2017bed0c047fd92960507e2e0ee8a54/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
...
```

However, when I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally, it goes through with no glitch, making the situation totally confusing to me.

In my `bower.json` file, I have: `"foundation-sites": "latest",`

Suffice it to say however, that when I entered heroku bash and checked the contents of `vendor/assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/_color.scss`, it's slightly different from my local version. but no mention of the complained `$color: "foreground(#09798e)"` in the file.

At the moment, I'm resigned to precompiling the assets locally before push, but it's getting too cumbersome and I need to figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem running my rails app locally. It looks like this error is due to a syntax change between gem foundation-rails 6.2.4 and 6.3.0.

I fixed this by specifying 6.2.4 in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 6.2.4'
```

Comment: Hmm... let me check the equivalent of this for bower... Thanks

Comment: Oh Yeahhh!!!! it worked! I changed `"foundation-sites": "latest",` to `"foundation-sites": "~> 6.2.4"` in my `bower.json` and heroku compile didn't break.